# How to use keras flow method?

Tags: dataset, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am building a Convolutional Neural Network with Keras. I want to use my own dataset. This dataset consists of matrices of specified size and filled with 0's which contain a submatrix of specified size and filled with 1's. The submatrix is optional and the goal is to train the NN to predict whether a matrix contains the submatrix or whether it doesnt. To make it more difficult to detect, I am adding various types of noise to the matrices.

Here is a picture of what the matrices look like, the black parts are 0's and the white part are 1's. There is a 1:1 correspondance between the pixels of the image and the entries in the matrix.
[image]

Now I want to create a CNN which can classify these images. The easiest approach so far was to use

```
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                            target_size = (imageSize, imageSize),
                                            batch_size = batchSize,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
```

And then I fill the directory `training_set` with 1000's of images. This works well, but has one major problem:

It is really inefficient, as I'm first creating images, saving them on a hard-dsik, then loading them again. These are a lot of unecessary steps, considering that keras transforms the images back into matrices (or tensors, idk), and my images were initially matrices.

Thus I was thinking about improving the efficiency by having the matrices in a `.csv` or even having my `matrixgenerator.py` "feed" a list or array directly into keras. I did some research and found the method [flow](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) from Keras which specifies as parameter an input matrix.

Unfortunately this is where I am stuck. **I do not understand how to get my matrices into the form keras wants. I also don't know the exact shape the matrices and labels need to have to be able to use the flow method.**

It would really help if someone could explain me how to use the flow method/tell me where I find more information on it, or give me a better option to feed my dataset into a keras CNN. Thank you for your help. I'm also ok with using a lower-level tensorflow implementation as long as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have resized and other preprocessing your image data into a multi-dimensional numpy array and split the data into training and test.

To use the flow() method. You first want to create a generator using ImageDataGenerator(). The example below DOES NOT DO image augmentation. It will feed only the images in your training set. I added the rescale parameter in case one had not normalized the pixel data.

You then pass your training data to the fit() method of the generator (datagen.fit()).

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) 
datagen.fit(x_train)
```

Now you can train your model using the fit_generator() method for your model.

```
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batchSize),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / batchSize, epochs=epochs)
```

You can do it the manual way:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batchSize):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
```

Here's the link to the corresponding Keras documentation: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately I'm not working on that project anymore, but I hope some future readers will find it helpful!